# Meaning of overdue

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In this sentence:

> I didn't get any *agenda.
>   I faxed one overdue this morning.

What does `overdue` mean?

(*Agenda in this sentence means a task list, for exemple: `Our agenda for today is: *Listen music *Dance`*)

Comment: "I faxed one overdue this morning." doesn't seem natural. But I suppose it means "I faxed one (agenda) *that was* overdue this morning." *overdue* refers to the agenda that was late.

Comment: I thought the same.

Comment: "agenda" doesn't make sense here - if you replace it with a word that makes sense (agendas, letters, emails, etc,) overdue makes more sense

Comment: If agenda in this case means `A task list`, for example. `Our agenda for today is: *Listen music *Dance`?

Comment: Please don't downvote this question. Both sentences are correct English, and it's nearly impossible to find an explanation in any source. We could use [more details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/6700) about the context, but the subject matter is perfect for ELL.

Comment: Please wait at least a day or so before accepting an answer. [This meta question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700) explains why this is usually wise. In this case, I think a good answer will explain why it's reasonable to use "overdue" as an adverb here (and maybe also what people mean when they say "any" where "an" is ordinary).

Comment: Ok, I got it @BenKovitz

Comment: "Overdue" is ambiguous here.  It appears to be abbreviated language where words obvious to the author are left out.  It could mean either an item that was overdue (missing word "item"), or the fact that the fax was late (sent after it was supposed to be sent); i.e., the meaning could be an item or timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> overdue

is used to describe a situation which is *late* or *past due*

> The library book should have been returned last week, it is now **overdue**.

Your sentence

> I faxed one **overdue** this morning.

is an incorrect use of "*overdue*", your might have meant

> I faxed one **late** this morning.

Your first sentence also is incorrect. If the conversation was about a meeting then your first sentence would be

> I didn't get **an** agenda *(for the meeting)*.

meaning they did not receive the *order* or *topics* of the meeting which should have been faxed beforehand, but were fixed too late for the meeting.

Comment: If agenda in this case means `A task list`, for example. `Our agenda for today is: *Listen music *Dance`?